# Facebook iOS SDK "Something went wrong" at login possible diagnostic

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, authentication

I think I've discovered why the iOS Facebook SDK shows something went wrong when you login to it.

I rarely get this problem, and the app I'm developing is being tested by some other people and they are always getting this error, so I started to think what my account had different to theirs and I found that I have a security setting meaning I need to enter the device name that I'm using when I log into my account from the device / simulator.

That view appears after I tap login, and this is where other people are getting an error, so I used a friends account to log in and sure enough, he had the problem and his security settings ignore saving new devices.

So I'm wondering, I think the Facebook SDK is trying to prompt the user to save the device to their account, and for the users who have this security feature disabled, the SDK runs into problems.

Also it's interesting to note that this doesn't stop the user being logged in, because when I try to share with Facebook just after, I am taken to my feed dialog view which I wanted from the start.

Any thoughts on this ?

[image]

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. It seems to have cropped up in the last couple of weeks. If I login separately, then post using the same dialog it works. Or if I attempt to post without being logged in, I get the login dialog, login, it hangs with the above message. I close it. Try to post again, I get the Post dialog and everything appears to work fine. It seems as though there is an issue with the transition between Login Dialog and Post Dialog. I updated the Facebook ios sdk with no results.

Comment: You're right, Passing from login to dialog I believe goes through some kind of check to see if it needs to ask you to save the device to your list of devices used to log into Facebook, I think this check is throwing an error if you have this setting off in your Facebook account, because every time I have this on it works fine, but off gives the screenshot you see above. I ended up using OAuth to log in and prompt the user with dialog when I had the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with as a workaround, though fair warning it isn't a proper solution. I don't really like it as it's very hacky, but it works for now.

Before showing a the stream dialog, I check to see if the user is logged in. If not, I show the login dialog and then trigger the stream dialog in the DidLogin callback.
Basically I'm avoiding the automatic Login to Post Dialog transition.

Comment: Hi, I never said this was a solution, for sure it's a hack however I think I've nailed the reason behind this "bug" if we can call it that, I'm sure Facebook are aware and any future updates should correct this.

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't referring to your work as hacky, just the workaround I ended up with. Your post was very helpful to me actually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case wrong permissions were the reason. Such a stupid missing. Maybe it will help anybody in the future..

Comment: hey - I'm coming across this issue too, what permissions were missing for the test user?

Comment: Hi! Now I pass only one permission "email".

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [official guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/) and make sure you have done all the steps.

1. Install the library
2. Add the Facebook-related settings to the info.plist
3. Add code to App Delegate
4. Add code to your login controller

In my case, I have the **permission string** wrong. I put "publicProfile" instead of "public_profile". The most common cause is having **wrong** FacebookAppID, Bundle Identifier, or permission.