# facebook authorize: opening Safari.app how do I get an in-app dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, dialog, authorization

I need to get some permissions for my Facebook implementation, however when I call the following method on my Facebook object, I'm being sent to Safari.app, but I've seen apps have a dialog for this, and that's what I want... How can I get a dialog as opposed to being sent to Safari ?

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator?

Comment: Testing in simulator and on device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Facebook.m file, change `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];` to `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];`

Comment: That worked, Facebook are having problems with their iOS SDK at the moment and a lot of users are getting "Something went wrong" message, but by requesting say publish permissions with OAuth, no error occurs. See my post about this Facebook issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082019/facebook-ios-sdk-something-went-wrong-at-login-possible-diagnostic